# match values and set variables in while loop - php

Tags: php

I am trying to match the variable names with the item in the array and setting a variable color based on values matched (i.e. passed is green and failed is red). I am not sure why the if condition isn't evaluated correctly.

```
<style type="text/css">
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space:pre-wrap; 
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-decoration:none;

}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    white-space:pre-wrap; 
    word-wrap:break-word;

 }

 .red {
     color: #FF0000; 
 }

.green {
    color: #008000;
}

</style>
<?php

header("My Dashboard");
$homdir = "/var/www/html/myfolder/";
$di     = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($homdir);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
if (pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "html") {
    $lines = file($filename);
    echo nl2br($lines[1]);
}
if (pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME) == "Results") {
    echo '
    <br />&nbsp;</p> 
    <table summary="My Table">
    <tr>
    <th>Test</th>
    <th>Results</th>
    </tr> <br />&nbsp;</p>';
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
    if (!$fp) {
        echo 'ERROR: Unable to open file.</table></body></html>';
        exit;
    }

    $row = 0;

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $row++;
        $line        = fgets($fp, 1024); //use 2048 if very long lines
        $field[$row] = explode(' ', $line);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    $arrays = count($field) - 1;

    $loop = 0;

    $passvalue="PASSED";
    $failvalue="FAILED";

    while ($loop < $arrays) {
        if ($field[$loop][2] == $passvalue) {
           $color="red";
        } elseif ($field[$loop][2] == $failvalue) {
           $color="green";
        }
        $loop++;
        echo '
            <tr>
               <td><a href="' . $field[$loop][1] . '" class='.$color'>'  .   $field[$loop][0] . '</a></td>
               <td>' . $field[$loop][2] . '</td>
           </tr>';
      }   
    }
  }
  ?>
```

Sample example flat file (which I am reading) to highlight TestURL in red if it FAILED or green if it PASSED.

```
Test1 TestURL PASSED
Test2 TestURL FAILED
Test3 TestURL PASSED
Test4 TestURL PASSED
```

Comment: It looks like your while loop is not correctly closed. It is missing the closing `}`.

Comment: @Lokesh Stackoverflow requires the _minimum example necessary to reproduce the problem_. Please don't truncate your code for our sake, just give us enough _valid code_ so we can find reproduce your problem ourselves. Invalid code isn't much use to anyone.

Comment: a `foreach()` loop would make this easier and less error prone

Comment: how do we know `$fp` isn't failing? what does http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php throw back, if anything? and how `$color` is used later on.

Comment: @Lokesh could you add var_dump( $field[$loop][2] ); at the begining of the loop and post output here?

Comment: @RobbieAverill, Fred I have included more information so its easier to reproduce the example. Anything else missing here?

Comment: @stweb here is the output: `NULL string(7) "PASSED " string(7) "FAILED " string(7) "FAILED " string(7) "FAILED " string(7) "PASSED " string(7) "FAILED " string(7) "PASSED " string(7) "FAILED "`

Comment: @Lokesh, replace  $loop = 0; with  $loop = 1;

Comment: @stweb I had tried that but the color var is still empty.

Comment: @Lokesh replace class=$color with class='.$color.'

Comment: @stweb still the colors are not being set. I also tried to print value of the variable color and its still empty.

Comment: @Lokesh I suggest you to avoid while loop and use foreach loop. This way you will minimize errors.

Comment: @Lokesh your color isn't set to the right css classes. change to "red" "Green". also for the loop, a general for loop can also work because of the way you are counting out your data.

Comment: @thebtm I did change the color to "red" and "green" in var assignment but still doesn't work

Comment: @Lokesh you are using single quotes over double quotes. single quotes are treated as literal and double quotes are relative.

Comment: @thebtm I updated the code as per your suggestion. Let me know if you still see issues.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your while loop with foreach loop:

```
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $row++;
    $line        = fgets($fp, 1024); //use 2048 if very long lines
    $fields[$row] = explode(' ', $line);
}
fclose($fp);
foreach( $fields as $item )[
  if( $item[2] == 'PASSED' ){
     $color  = 'color: #008000;';
  } elseif ( $item[2] == 'FAILED' ){
     $color = 'color: #FF0000;';
  }
  echo '
        <tr>
           <td><a href="' . $item[1] . '" style="'.$color'">' . $item[0] . '</a></td>
           <td>' . $item[2] . '</td>
       </tr>';
}
```

Comment: How do I write the output to the table in this case?

Comment: @Lokesh I've added output to answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all your help. After digging deeper I figured out there was an extra white space being added in the string hence the pattern matching was always failing though when I was printing it on the screen I didn't notice anything wrong. So there was nothing wrong in the program and in order to fix this problem I removed the extra whitespace using trim (http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function and then compared the strings which actually resolved this issue.